# In Bootstrap 3 where can you change the background color (default is blue) on form select hover

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover

Hi does anyone know how to change the hover background colour on bootstrap3 on a form? Thanks Graeme

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can use this style

```
<style>
    form:hover {
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, unfortunately that doesnt work, i have now realised that it isnt css or js related but seems to be a core windows component, i tried stripping out all the js and css and it still shows the blue background colour when you hover